# How to pass the predefined messages from one page to another page using php

Tags: php, url, post

I want to pass a predefined message from a PHP page to another.i having button if user clicks the button its will redirect to the contact form page when its redirect it will show the predefined message in a message box.

e.g. let's say that I have these message:

```
$message="Dear xxxxxxxx Team,

I am interested in an xxxxx.

Kind Regards,
xxxx";
```

and I want to pass them from index.php to contactform.php.

I trying like with URL

```
<a href="contact_form.php?message=$message"  class="tbutton large"><i class="arrow_right" ></i><i style="margin:0 0 0 0px" class="icon_comment_alt"></i><span>Get a xxxxx - Messenger Test Account</span></a>
```

but it not working can anyone tell me how to make it work

Comment: Why would u send all that data over http while you could just generate that information on the result page?

Comment: If these are predefined messages why are you passing them from page to page and not placing them in a config file of some sort and passing a reference to them such as an array index key or something of the sort?

Answer (score 1):

try this `<?php echo urlencode($message);?>`

like this

```
<a href="contact_form.php?message=<?php echo urlencode($message);?>"  class="tbutton large"><i class="arrow_right" ></i><i style="margin:0 0 0 0px" class="icon_comment_alt"></i><span>Get a xxxxx - Messenger Test Account</span></a>
```

**METHOD : 2**

use session to store your static message like

```
$message "some message";
$_SESSION['static_message'] = $msg;
```

Now use simple link without passing the parameter

```
<a href="contact_form.php"  class="tbutton large"><i class="arrow_right" ></i><i style="margin:0 0 0 0px" class="icon_comment_alt"></i><span>Get a xxxxx - Messenger Test Account</span></a>
```

Now on `contact_form.php` you can access this like

```
$message = $_SESSION['static_message'];
```

**NOTE :** you have to start the session on the top of the page where you are using session by using line  `session_start();`

Comment: @SecondRikudo i have updated my answer with some more details

Comment: @SKRocks can explain more about the method 2

Comment: @Xavi updated i was writing the answer when you comment

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass long strings in a GET parameter.

Your best bet is using **[Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)**

```
session_start(); //This must happen on each page where the session is used!
$_SESSION["message"] = <<<MESSAGE
Dear xxxxxxxx Team,

I am interested in an xxxxx.

Kind Regards,
Raja
MESSAGE;
```

Then on your contact page you'd `echo` it out on the page like this:

```
<?= $_SESSION["message"] ?>
```

Note that you must use `session_start()` at the top of the contact page as well!

Also, it might be a good idea to wipe the session clean (`$_SESSION = array();`) after you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $_SESSION variables to this, so on the first page (index.php) you could use:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = 'Dear xxxxxxxx Team, I am interested in an xxxxx. Kind Regards, Raja';
?>
```

So you assign the value of a session variable.

and on contact.php it would be just simply

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['message']; unset($_SESSION['message']); session_destroy(); ?>
```

You can change the echo part to suit your needs. Unset destroys the value of the variable and session_destroy discards the whole session.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Alex can tell me what if i have two types of messages like $message1="xxx",$message2="xxx",if i click the button it will show the message1 anf i dont click the button i will show message2 is it possible

Comment: @Xavi - if I understand you correctly that's more logic to implement. I'll just try to demonstrate: What I would do in the first place is to initialize both strings `$_SESSION['message1'] = "xxx"; $_SESSION['message2'] = "xxx";` Clicking the button would for example point to a location like `contact.php?button=1` and then contact.php could look for that using `IF(ISSET($_GET['button']) && $_GET['button'] == 1) { echo $_SESSION['message1']; } else { echo $_SESSION['message2']; }` Hope this makes sense to you. This can be done quite a few ways, this is just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

To pass predefined message, one way is, add form in index.php with required action and between the form add submit button and one hidden field of for predefined message.
ex:

```
    <form name="test" id="test" action="contact_form.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="msg" is="msg" value="I am interested in an xxxxx"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Messenger Test Account"/>
    </form>
```

You can get message on contact_form.php page using echo $_POST['msg'];

The other way is,

```
<a href="contact_form.php?message=1"  class="tbutton large"><i class="arrow_right" ></i><i style="margin:0 0 0 0px" class="icon_comment_alt"></i><span>Get a xxxxx - Messenger Test Account</span></a>
```

on contact_form.php check

```
isset($_GET['message'] && $_GET['message']==1) { echo "I am interested in an xxxxx"; }
```

But the best way is the first one where we pass message using post method.